# Dubai transit visa matter

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, paperwork, dxb

I am an indian passport holder. I am going to Mogadishu from Delhi via Dubai. My transit time is 6-7 hours at Dubai airport. Also, I have different flights (Air India & Jubba airways). My first flight arrives at terminal 1 and my seconds flight departs from terminal 2. Also I have a check-in luggage.

Do I need a transit visa in Dubai?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you're on separate tickets and have to collect luggage, you'll have to clear immigration in Dubai, for which you need a transit visa.

So yes, you do need a visa, which you can get through [Air India](http://airindiaexpress.in/onlinevisa_uae.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a transit visa for Dubai, especially as you will not have a boarding pass for Mogadishu when you board in Delhi.

In fact, I doubt if Air India will let you board without a visa for Dubai.